# ADF Pipeline triggers schedule time not updating from DEV to UAT/PROD

Tags: azure-data-factory

I created a trigger in DEV ADF and scheduled it for a specific time and then deployed to UAT ADF using ARM Template.
Later, I modified the scheduled time in DEV ADF for those trigger and redeployed the same to move the changes into UAT ADF using ARM Template. but the trigger in UAT ADF is not getting updated with the rescheduled time.

Changed in DEV

[image]

not updated in UAT

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To update active triggers, you need to manually stop them and then restart them after the deployment.

Step1: You need to use a powershell script that disables all the active triggers in ADF.

Step2: Deploy the ADF arm template ( have a common arm template for all environments)

Refer this [answer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/406374/adf-pipeline-trigger-deployment-on-devops.html) by nandanhegde

Also refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery#updating-active-triggers